# Any good way to position UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete icon within a grouped tableview?

Tags: iphone

as title, can i position the UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete button/icon to be within the tableviewcell of a grouped tableview rather than outside of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An excerpt from a [Matt Gallagher](http://cocoawithlove.com/) [blog post](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/01/multiple-row-selection-and-editing-in.html) reveals a method

This is the original code to mimic the behavior you DON'T want:

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self setNeedsLayout];
}

- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];

    [super layoutSubviews];

    if (((UITableView *)self.superview).isEditing)
    {

        CGRect contentFrame = self.contentView.frame;
        contentFrame.origin.x = EDITING_HORIZONTAL_OFFSET;
        self.contentView.frame = contentFrame;
    }
    else
    {
        CGRect contentFrame = self.contentView.frame;
        contentFrame.origin.x = 0;
        self.contentView.frame = contentFrame;
    }

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

So if we made a change, we can make it do what you do want:

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self setNeedsLayout];
}

- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];

    [super layoutSubviews];

    if (((UITableView *)self.superview).isEditing)
    {
        //don't resize and and move your frame here

        CGRect contentFrame = self.contentView.frame;
        contentFrame.origin.x = 0;
        self.contentView.frame = contentFrame;
    }
    else
    {
        CGRect contentFrame = self.contentView.frame;
        contentFrame.origin.x = 0;
        self.contentView.frame = contentFrame;
    }

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

You'll proabably have to tweak this, but it is a good start.